# Assign value of a subscription to the property of a class without mutation

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, immutability, object-oriented-analysis

Up until now I have been doing the following to assign the value of a subscription to a property on my classes:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  exampleId: string;

  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => this.exampleId = params.id);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Do something with exampleId here...
  }
}
```

In an effort to move away from mutation and more towards immutability; I hope to assign the value that is returned from that subscription to the `exampleId` property without needing to do so in the constructor.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: you can do it in the OnInit life cycle

Comment: That still mutates the original property definition. I need to assign the value at the time of the property creation.

Comment: there is a snapshot alternative to get route params without using observable subscription [link](https://angular.io/guide/router#snapshot-the-no-observable-alternative)

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately the route is just an example and not really part of the question at hand. What I am looking for is a way to assign the value of any subscription to any property on any class without causing mutation.

Comment: The idea of subscription is that the main property that you are searching for might not be ready yet to get it, or it changes durant time, so you subscribe to it to be notified of any changes.

Comment: The only best practices you can do , as far as i know, is to avoid waiting the value in the constructor and do a async pipe waiting for it in the template of the component.

Comment: You know that you example is kinda useless, because a `string` in javascript is immutable by design. Immutability in javascript is a concern when using arrays or objects. (e.g. `var a = 'a'; a = 'b';` isn't a mutation of the value of `a`, but `var a = ['a']; a[0] = 'b';` is a mutation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any asynchronous request you make from the constructor means your `Component` won't be immutable: it necessarily has two states; before and after the data has resolved.

Therefore if you want an immutable component you have to move the asynchronous part out of the `Component` and fetch the data before it is constructed. For the example you gave this can be done using a routing Resolve service and a `resolve` object in the routing configuration. Then the router will resolve the data before the component is instantiated and it can be accessed through `ActivatedRouteSnapshot.data`.

For a more general case to make any class immutable when that class depends on asynchronous data, you need some kind of factory that will resolve the data and make it available to the class on construction (here the router is that factory).